# Print statement not all appearing at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a confusing issue in some code I'm currently running in a Jupyter notebook. I am reading in a couple thousand text files, each of them tens of MB, with Pandas, and searching for certain values within them. To track the progress while this happens, I threw in some print statements every once in a while. The important pieces of the code here are:

```
read_dir = '/Volumes/Data/'
all_text_files = os.listdir(read_dir)
all_text_files.sort()
# Split the file up so we at least get some output if this doesn't finish running
file_chunks = [all_text_files[i:i+100] for i in range(0,len(all_text_files),100)]

for chunk_num, current_chunk in enumerate(file_chunks):
    print('Chunk', chunk_num)
    for file_num, file in enumerate(current_chunk):
        if file_num % 10 == 0:
            print('File', file_num, '-', file)
    # Read in the data down here
```

Normally, I see a bunch of print statements like

```
File 10 - some_file.txt
```

However, I recently saw one of these print statements stall midway. That is, the Jupyter output sat at `File 10 -` for a couple of minutes, and then eventually it completed to the above line, and the code continued to run.

Any idea how it got stuck in the middle of a print statement like that? Is that stalling likely within the Python `print` function, or is it in displaying that output on the Jupyter notebook? And finally, is there any information to take away about this - has something in my own code potentially caused this?

Comment: there is no way to easily recreate this problem.

Comment: I agree... I'm just looking for thoughts on what makes it possible for a print statement to freeze halfway through.

Comment: the issue is, it might have been some type of local problem. because of that, it is very hard to answer.

Comment: Try adding `flush=True` to the print parameter list, i.e.: `print('File', file_num, '-', file, flush=True)`.  This will avoid buffering, in case that's related to the problem you're seeing.